# ios slider action in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I've a `UISlider` in a `UITableViewCell` error.

[image: this my UITableViewCell]

When I click slider, then it puts this:

```
 -[MyCell slider:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf81d82ab0
    2016-04-10 22:24:49.947 TableViewController3[2372:153428] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyCell slider:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcf81d82ab0'
```

Here's my code

**my TableViewCell class**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface MyCell : UITableViewCell


    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *questionText;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *slider_value_text;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
    @end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------    


    #import "MyCell.h"

    @implementation MyCell

    - (void)awakeFromNib {
        [super awakeFromNib];
        // Initialization code
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @end
```

---

**my UITableViewController class**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyCell.h"
@interface myTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property NSArray *arr1;
-(void)Selector:(id)sender;
@end
```

---

```
  #import "myTableViewController.h"

@interface myTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation myTableViewController
@synthesize  arr1;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"here amq");
    arr1=@[@"homer",@"marge",@"lisa",@"asd eq hayde ewqewqsdaqww asd sad beklqwee awe qwe"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return [arr1 count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.questionText.text=[arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell slider ] setMaximumValue:1];
    [[cell slider ] setMaximumValue:5];
    [[cell slider ] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[cell slider] setTag:indexPath.row];
    [[cell slider] addTarget:self action:@selector(generalSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    return cell;
}

-(void)Selector:(id)sender{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]){
        UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
        NSLog(@"Slider value %f",slider.value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the crash?

Comment: when I clicked   the slider on app screen,error occurs in 
main.m this line ""return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]))""  ->Theard1 SIGABRT

Comment: Do you have a generalSelector: method in your myTableViewController implementation?

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how to debug a crash. Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 for some helpful info.

Comment: I dont know,what is   differences   between generalSelector    and regular selector method?,

Comment: @FatihAltuntaş Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `generalSelector:` with the actual name of the selector you want to call when the slider changes his value.
In this case you should replace `generalSelector:` with `Selector:`
Read this if you want an explanation of what is a selector: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html

Comment: If he solved your problem, accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. Also upvote it if you want.